# Event listener is not removed in useEffect call within function-based component

Tags: reactjs, dom

Imagine we have a simple function-based component with a checkbox.

I'm curious to find out why subsequent addition and removal of event listeners succeeds:

```
function Component() {
  const handler = () => 123

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler)
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler)
  }, [isChecked])
}
```

But when a condition is introduced, for instance:

```
function Component() {
  const handler = () => 123

  useEffect(() => {
    isChecked
      ? window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler)
      : window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler)
  }, [isChecked])
}
```

Listeners are added but not removed anymore.

Why is that? Is it because our handler is recreated on re-render? When handler is moved outside of the component, everything is in order.

---

Here's a demo for those who'd like to test it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/y8jono6yx?module=%2Fsrc%2FCheckbox.jsx

Instructions:

- Download project files (top bar menu)
- Run `npm i` within downloaded folder
- Spin up dev server with `npm start`

A list of event listeners could be retrieved by calling `getEventListeners(window)` - at least in Chrome.

Comment: The body of the question doesn't include `Checkbox` itself and may give wrong impression about where `handler` is defined.

Comment: Good point. It’s assumed. I guess I’d better been explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `handler` is new function on each component render. `window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler)` is no-op because this `handler` function was never registered as `beforeunload` listener.

`handler` should be moved outside the scope of component function:

```
const handler = () => 123;

export default function Checkbox() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(
    () => {
      isChecked
        ? window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler)
        : window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
    },
    [isChecked]
  );
  ...
};
```

Since `handler` doesn't have access to component function scope this way, things that can be done there are very limited. A more conventional way is to make `useEffect` callback be executed only once (a counterpart to `componentDidMount`) and return a function from `useEffect` (a counterpart to `componentWillUnmount`). Since same `handler` is used in the scope of `useEffect` function, the problem disappears, but another problem is that `handler` cannot be used together with `useState` because `handler` that is used in `useEffect` is a function that was defined during initial render and `isChecked` will be always `false` in its scope. `useRef` can be used for this purpose instead (a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p70nxrr2j)):

```
export default function Checkbox() {
  const isCheckedRef = useRef(false);
  const handler = () => {
    if (isCheckedRef.current)
      ...
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      checked={isCheckedRef.current}
      onChange={e => isCheckedRef.current = e.target.checked}
    />
  );
}
```